# Inequação em linguagem C

Tags: c, algoritmo, matemática

Dados: Brutus tem 1,84m e pesa 122kg e Olívia tem 1,76m e pesa 45kg.

```
IMC = peso/(altura*altura);

IMC: 18,5 a 25 -----> Saudável
```

Quero criar um algoritmo que imprima qual é a quantidade **MÍNIMA** de
quilos que Brutus e Olívia devem perder/ganhar para atingirem um peso saudável segundo a classificação do IMC.

Pensei em usar uma inequação, como no exemplo abaixo para o Brutus:

```
peso_a_perder = peso - x / (altura * altura) <= 25;
```

Fiz uma rápida pesquisa e não achei uma função de inequação na biblioteca `math.h`. Segue abaixo parte do código.

```
float imc_Brutus, imc_Olivia, peso_Brutus = 122, altura_Brutus = 1.84, peso_Olivia = 45, altura_Olivia = 1.76;
/*
O calculo do IMC dos dois esta aqui (omisso)
*/

float x, peso_a_perder_Brutus, peso_a_perder_Olivia;
peso_a_perder_Brutus = peso_Brutus - x / (altura_Brutus * altura_Brutus) <= 25;
printf("Brutus deve perder %0.2f kg para atingir um peso saudavel\n", peso_a_perder_Brutus);
printf("Olivia deve ganhar %0.2f kg para atingir um peso saudavel\n", peso_a_perder_Olivia);
```

**OBS:** **Devo criar o algoritmo usando conhecimentos bem básicos de C** (não incluir comandos condicionais, comandos de repetição, vetor, matriz, etc...)

**OBS2:** Saídas:

> - Brutus precisa perder no mínimo 37.36 quilos.
> - Olivia precisa ganhar no mínimo 12.31 quilos.

Pergunta extra: Qual seria o método mais eficiente de resolver esse cálculo? Inequação mesmo, ou *outra coisa*?

Comment: O tempo normalmente não vai ser tão absurdamente distinto. Cálculos matemáticos de tipos primitivos  são executados em tempo constante. Quando se tenta fazer algo mais eficiente, normalmente tenta-se diminuir a complexidade de execução do algoritmo; por exemplo, fazer uma ordenação em `o(n log n)` é muito mais eficiente do que `o(n^2)`, então não faz muito sentido questionar como escovar bits para deixar a ordenação quadrática mais eficiente

Comment: Fizeram recentemente uma questão sobre performance entre um algoritmo `o(n^2)` e outro `o(n log n)`. Compartilhei [meus resultados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/235636/64969) e as metodologias usadas. Olha a diferença entre a performance do `selection sort` para o `merge (3)`. Isso é o poder de diminuir a complexidade do algoritmo que resolve o problema

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pela [definição do IMC](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%8Dndice_de_massa_corporal), saudável seria de 18,5 até 25.

Primeiro, vamos criar uma função para calcular o IMC:

```
float imc(float peso, float altura) {
    return peso / (altura * altura);
}
```

Poderíamos também criar uma função que diga se o IMC é saudável ou não (mas nem vamos precisar aqui):

```
int imc_saudavel(float imc) {
    return imc >= 18.5 && imc <= 25;
}
```

> Se *fulano* tem um IMC baixo, quanto peso ele precisa ganhar para chegar em 18,5?

Vamos resolver a equação:

```
imc(peso_atual + peso_a_ganhar, altura) = 18,5
(peso_atual + peso_a_ganhar) / (altura * altura) = 18,5
peso_atual + peso_a_ganhar = 18,5 * altura * altura
peso_a_ganhar = 18,5 * altura * altura - peso_atual
```

> E se for acima de 25, quanto ele tem que perder?

```
imc(peso_atual - peso_a_perder, altura) = 25
(peso_atual - peso_a_perder) / (altura * altura) = 25
peso_atual - peso_a_perder = 25 * altura * altura
-peso_a_perder = 25 * altura * altura - peso_atual
```

Considerando que `peso_a_perder = -peso_a_ganhar`, então:

```
peso_a_ganhar = 25 * altura * altura - peso_atual
```

Em ambos os casos, temos isso:

```
peso_a_ganhar = imc_ideal * altura * altura - peso_atual
```

Então, podemos fazer uma função que diz quanto peso uma pessoa deve ganhar ou perder:

```
float peso_a_variar(float peso, float altura) {
    float valorImc = imc(peso, altura);
    if (valorImc >= 18.5 && valorImc <= 25) return 0; // A pessoa já tem o IMC saudável.
    float fator = valorImc < 18.5 ? 18.5 : 25; 
    return fator * altura * altura - peso;
}
```

Observe as inequações nestes `if`s e no uso do operador ternário. O resto se baseia em equações.

> Posso eliminar esse `if`?

Se a pessoa já tiver um peso ideal, poderíamos eliminar o `if` ao usar como `fator`, o próprio `valorImc`. Uma vez que nesse caso:

```
valorImc = peso / (altura * altura)
```

Então o `return` iria produzir isso:

```
(peso / (altura * altura)) * altura * altura - peso
```

Observe que `peso` é dividido por `altura * altura` e depois multiplicado por esse mesmo termo. Essas duas operações se anulam, de forma que isso resulta em:

```
peso - peso
```

O que obviamente é sempre zero. Logo, se a pessoa já tiver peso ideal, podemos usar o `valorImc` no lugar do `fator`. Isso deixa o código um pouco mais simples:

```
float peso_a_variar(float peso, float altura) {
    float valorImc = imc(peso, altura);
    float fator = valorImc < 18.5 ? 18.5 : valorImc > 25 ? 25 : valorImc; 
    return fator * altura * altura - peso;
}
```

> Posso eliminar esses operadores ternários?

A função desses operadores ternários é garantir que o fator esteja dentro da faixa saudável de 18,5 até 25. Logo, você pode substituí-los ao usar o [`fminf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmin) e o [`fmaxf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmax) (não esqueça o `#include <math.h>`):

```
float peso_a_variar(float peso, float altura) {
    float valorImc = imc(peso, altura);
    float fator = fmaxf(18.5, fminf(valorImc, 25.0)); 
    return fator * altura * altura - peso;
}
```

Se não quiser usar funções que já não estejam prontas na biblioteca padrão também:

```
float peso_fulano = ...;
float altura_fulano = ...;
float imc_fulano = peso_fulano / (altura_fulano * altura_fulano);
float fator_fulano = fmaxf(18.5, fminf(imc_fulano, 25.0)); 
float peso_a_ganhar_fulano = fator_fulano * altura_fulano * altura_fulano - peso_fulano;
```

E você tem como resultado um código que usa apenas conhecimentos bem básicos em C.

Comment: gostei mesmo desta explicação +1

Comment: Tomando como exemplo o caso do Brutus, vou ficar com a resolução da equação msm, sem nem usar a biblioteca `math.h`. Ou seja, usarei a ` - peso_a_perder = 25 * altura * altura - peso_atual`

Comment: A explicação ficou muito boa!