# Qual o modo mais performático de converter int[] para int?

Tags: java, desempenho

Qual o modo mais performático de converter as posições invertidas de um `array` para `int`? Por exemplo, o seguinte `array` deve resultar no inteiro `153` para efeitos de cálculo futuro:

```
int[] a = new int[] {3, 5, 1};
```

Pensei em duas formas, porém não consegui identificar um bom modo de testar qual tem um desempenho melhor e também não sei se alguma delas é realmente a melhor forma. Vou listá-las abaixo.

---

Forma 1:

```
private int arrayToInt(int[] numeros) {
  int resultado = 0;
  int multiplicador = 1;

  for (int numero : numeros) {
    resultado = resultado + (numero * multiplicador);
    multiplicador = multiplicador * 10;
  }

  return resultado;
}
```

---

Forma 2:

```
private int arrayToInt(int[] numeros) {
  StringBuilder construtor = new StringBuilder();

  for (int numero : numeros) {
    construtor.append(numero);
  }

  return Integer.parseInt(construtor.reverse().toString());
}
```

Comment: Na ordem inversa mesmo? Primeiro unidades e depois dezenas?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado isso mesmo!

Comment: Devido ao `int` ter no máximo 9 dígitos, posso assumir que o tamanho máximo do `array` é 9?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado sim, não precisa cobrir todos os casos. Na realidade o que importa mesmo é o desempenho. Eu consegui pensar em algumas formas mas não pensei muito bem em como testar, por isso resolvi perguntar, no caso de alguém saber qual o melhor e saber explicar o porquê

Comment: Eu creio que medir o melhor seja saber exatamente quantas chamadas de quais bytecodes serão feitas, assim como também alguns detalhes de localidade e o peso de chamada por bytecode. Estou bolando aqui um jeito, feio (com direito a `switch`) porém creio que seja o mais rápido.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado tem dois modos que eu pensei aqui também, vou editar a pergunta e colocar os dois ali, só que ainda fica a dúvida de qual é o melhor justamente porque não consegui bolar uma forma de testar

Comment: Trabalhar com strings será mais lento que o primeiro jeito, não tenha dúvida... Criação de `a.length` objetos distintos será mais caro do que qualquer multiplicação que você faça. Estou incluindo na minha resposta também um jeito de comparação de performance baseado [neste aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/235636/64969)

Comment: Vou terminar a resposta outro dia, ela ainda não está pronta para ser postada e já está mais tarde do que eu havia dado conta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conforme eu [comentei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/258425/qual-o-modo-mais-perform%c3%a1tico-de-converter-int-para-int?noredirect=1#comment529977_258425), creio que, para se ter uma noção geral de como a sua soma vai ser performática ou não, você precisaria analisar os bytecodes que serão chamados e o peso geral que eles tem relativos um ao outro. Também seria adequado fazer o melhor uso possível da localidade das variáveis, otimizando o uso do *cache* do processador.

Vou dividir essa resposta em duas seções (além desta introdutória):

- uma função otimizada (veja próximo parágrafo sobre o que está sendo levado em consideração)
- como testar e por em contra-ponto diversas soluções

Vou considerar aqui que chamadas JNI estão fora de cogitação. Também não vou considerar o efeito que o `jitter` possa vir a ter. Apenas uma análise teórica. Também vou pular otimizações do próprio compilador.

## Função de soma otimizada

O resultado obtido é um `int`, então sabemos que no máximo o número valerá `2^31 - 1`, o que dá 10 casas decimais. Portanto, o vetor terá no máximo tamanho 10.

Como o tamanho do vetor é limitado (variando de 1 a 10; não considerando o caso trivial de tamanho 0), podemos tentar resolver de duas maneiras:

- método iterativo (em que vou percorrendo cada elemento do vetor individialmente)
- somatório para cada tamanho

A vantagem do método iterativo é que se escreve menos código. Imagino escrever o método iterativo de duas maneiras diferentes: ascendente e descendente. Vamos dar uma olhada nelas?

```
int soma_asc(int []a) {
  int base = 1;
  int acc = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    acc += a[i] * base;
    base *= 10;
  }

  return acc;
}
```

Vou ficar devendo os bytecodes propriamente ditos, mas por cima o laço ficaria:

1. iniciar as variáveis `acc`, `base` e `i` com suas constantes
   `iconst_0, istore_2, iconst_1, istore_1, iconst_0, istore_3`
2. carregar a variável `i` na pilha
   `iload_3`
3. resgate do tamanho do vetor, deixando-o na pilha
   `aload_0, arraylength`
4. compara esses valores, caindo fora caso dê falsa a comparação
   `if_icmpge:13`
5. acessar o valor do vetor na posição `i`
   `aload_0, iload_3, iaload`
6. carregar `base` na pilha e multiplicar pelo valor anteriormente obtido
   `iload_1, imul`
7. carregar o antigo valor `acc`, somar com o valor anteriormente obtido, armazenar de volta em `acc`
   `iload_2, iadd, istore_2`
8. carregar `base`, carregar a constante 10, multiplicar e armazenar de volta em `base`
   `iload_1, ldc:#10, imult, istore_1`
9. incrementar `i`
   `iinc:3:1`
10. carregar a variável `i` na pilha
    `iload_3`
11. resgate do tamanho do vetor, deixando-o na pilha
    `aload_0, arraylength`
12. compara esses valores, voltando ao passo 4 caso dê verdadeira a comparação
    `if_icmplt:5`
13. carrega o valor de `acc` para ser retornado, retornando logo em seguida
    `iload_2, ireturn`

Tomemos como exemplo um vetor de tamanho 3. Serão executados os reguintes bytecodes (linhas começadas por `;` são comentários):

```
iconst_0, istore_2, iconst_1, istore_1, iconst_0, istore_3
iload_3
aload_0, arraylength
if_icmpge:13
aload_0, iload_3, iaload
iload_1, imul
iload_2, iadd, istore_2
iload_1, ldc:#10, imult, istore_1
iinc:3:1
iload_3
aload_0, arraylength
if_icmplt:5
; terminou de executar a tarefa referente ao primeiro dígito

aload_0, iload_3, iaload
iload_1, imul
iload_2, iadd, istore_2
iload_1, ldc:#10, imult, istore_1
iinc:3:1
iload_3
aload_0, arraylength
if_icmplt:5
; terminou de executar a tarefa referente ao segundo dígito

aload_0, iload_3, iaload
iload_1, imul
iload_2, iadd, istore_2
iload_1, ldc:#10, imult, istore_1
iinc:3:1
iload_3
aload_0, arraylength
if_icmplt:5
; terminou de executar a tarefa referente ao terceiro e último dígito

iload_2, ireturn
```

Um total de 57 bytecodes foram executados aqui, com dois desvios de fluxo. Foram feitos 37 acessos de leitura de informações da memória (3 acessos à `heap`), 9 acessos de escrita.

Se fossem 4 dígitos, teríamos +17 execuções de bytecodes, +1 desvio de fluxo, +11 acessos de leitura à memória (+1 acesso à `heap`), +2 acessos de escrita.

Note que essa função `soma_asc` pode ser reescrita com o açúcar-sintático da notação `foreach`, com a diferença de que `a[i]` ficaria armazenado em uma variável `v`:

```
int soma_foreach(int []a) {
  int base = 1;
  int acc = 0;

  for (int v: a) {
    acc += v * base;
    base *= 10;
  }

  return acc;
}
```

Isso implicaria no uso de alguns bytecodes de modo distinto, se não me engano afetando apenas o passo 4:

4. carregar o valor de `a[i]` na variável `v`, e então carregar o valor de `v` na pilha
   `aload_0, iload_3, iaload, istore#4, iload#4`

Isso implica em, para cada conjunto de instruções, mais um acesso de escrita e outro de leitura. Portanto, sem considerar possíveis otimizações do compilador, seria dois bytecodes pior por cada número no vetor de entrada.

A função `soma_desc` tem outra abordagem, indo da ponta final até o índice alcançar zero:

```
int soma_desc(int []a) {
  int acc = 0;

  for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    acc = acc*10 + a[i];
  }

  return acc;
}
```

Por cima, em uma análise semelhante ao que foi feito na função anterior:

1. incializar `acc` com a constante 0
   `iconst_0, istore_1`
2. carregar o tamanho de `a`, subtrair 1 e armazenar em `i`
   `aload_0, arraylength, iconst_1, isub, istore_2`
3. verificar se deve fazer o salto
   `iload_2, iconst_0, if_icmplt:6`
4. resgatar `acc`, multiplicar por 10, somar com `a[i]`, guardar em `acc`
   `iload_1, ldc:#10, imult, aload_0, iload_2, aiload, iadd, istore_1`
5. incrementar `i` e verificar se continua no laço
   `iinc:1:-1, iconst_0, if_icmpge:4`
6. carregar o valor de `acc` e retornar
   `iload_1, ireturn`

Novamente, se for feito para o vetor com 3 elementos:

```
iconst_0, istore_1
aload_0, arraylength, iconst_1, isub, istore_2
iload_2, iconst_0, if_icmplt:6
iload_1, ldc:#10, imult, aload_0, iload_2, aiload, iadd, istore_1
iinc:1:-1, iconst_0, if_icmpge:4
; terminou o primeiro laço

iload_1, ldc:#10, imult, aload_0, iload_2, aiload, iadd, istore_1
iinc:1:-1, iconst_0, if_icmpge:4
; terminou o segundo laço

iload_1, ldc:#10, imult, aload_0, iload_2, aiload, iadd, istore_1
iinc:1:-1, iconst_0, if_icmpge:4
; terminou o terceiro e último laço
iload_1, ireturn
```

+11 bytecodes por laço, 2 bytecodes de terminação e 10 bytecodes de início, para um total de 45 bytecodes executados. 5 acessos de escrita ao todo (sendo 1 por laço), 4 acessos de leitura por laço (sendo 1 de leitura da `heap`) mais 1 leitura na terminação mais 1 acesso de leitura de `heap` e 1 acesso de leitura de variável no início, totalizando então 7 acessos de leitura (3 de `heap`). Também contou com 2 desvios de fluxo.

É, esse algoritmo aparantou ser mais rápido...

Agora, como eu sei o tamanho máximo do vetor usado, eu posso fazer a soma adequada para tamanho, sem envolver iteração alguma:

```
int soma_desenrolada_1(int []a) {
  switch (a.length) {
  case 0: return 0;
  case 1: return a[0];
  case 2: return a[0] + a[1]*10;
  case 3: return a[0] + a[1]*10 + a[2]*100;
  case 4: return a[0] + a[1]*10 + a[2]*100 + a[3]*1_000;
  case 5: return a[0] + a[1]*10 + a[2]*100 + a[3]*1_000 + a[4]*10_000;
  case 6: return a[0] + a[1]*10 + a[2]*100 + a[3]*1_000 + a[4]*10_000 + a[5]*100_000;
  case 7: return a[0] + a[1]*10 + a[2]*100 + a[3]*1_000 + a[4]*10_000 + a[5]*100_000 + a[6]*1_000_000;
  case 8: return a[0] + a[1]*10 + a[2]*100 + a[3]*1_000 + a[4]*10_000 + a[5]*100_000 + a[6]*1_000_000 + a[7]*10_000_000;
  case 9: return a[0] + a[1]*10 + a[2]*100 + a[3]*1_000 + a[4]*10_000 + a[5]*100_000 + a[6]*1_000_000 + a[8]*100_000_000;
  case 10: return a[0] + a[1]*10 + a[2]*100 + a[3]*1_000 + a[4]*10_000 + a[5]*100_000 + a[6]*1_000_000 + a[8]*100_000_000 + a[9]*1_000_000_000;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Eu não sei como o Java vai compilar o `switch` para bytecodes, mas tem como prever o comportamento após isso. A soma que ele vai realizar. Peguemos para o caso com tamanho do vetor sendo 3 para comparar:

```
; coloca a[0] no topo
aload_0, iconst_0, aiload
; coloca a[1] no topo, multiplica por 10 e soma
aload_0, iconst_1, aiload, ldc#10, imul, iadd
; coloca a[2] no topo, multiplica por 100 e soma
aload_0, iconst_2, aiload, ldc#100, imul, iadd
; resposta obtida, só retornar
ireturn
```

Simples assim. Executando 16 bytecodes (compare com os outros que, para cada incremento no tamanho do vetor subia mais de 10 bytecodes), 3 acessos de leitura ao `heap`, nenhuma escrita de variável. Interessante, não é?

Podemos tentar diminuir a quantidade de constantes sendo multiplicada botanto o 10 em evidência. Assim, só haverá multiplicações por 10, por mais nenhum outro valor. Isso vai exigir colocar alguns parênteses a mais:

```
int soma_desenrolada_2(int []a) {
  switch (a.length) {
  case 0: return 0;
  case 1: return a[0];
  case 2: return a[0] + a[1]*10;
  case 3: return a[0] + 10*(a[1] + 10*(a[2]));
  case 4: return a[0] + 10*(a[1] + 10*(a[2] + 10*(a[3])));
  case 5: return a[0] + 10*(a[1] + 10*(a[2] + 10*(a[3] + 10*(a[4]))));
  case 6: return a[0] + 10*(a[1] + 10*(a[2] + 10*(a[3] + 10*(a[4] + 10*(a[5])))));
  case 7: return a[0] + 10*(a[1] + 10*(a[2] + 10*(a[3] + 10*(a[4] + 10*(a[5] + 10*(a[6]))))));
  case 8: return a[0] + 10*(a[1] + 10*(a[2] + 10*(a[3] + 10*(a[4] + 10*(a[5] + 10*(a[6] + 10*(a[7])))))));
  case 9: return a[0] + 10*(a[1] + 10*(a[2] + 10*(a[3] + 10*(a[4] + 10*(a[5] + 10*(a[6] + 10*(a[7] + 10*(a[8]))))))));
  case 10: return a[0] + 10*(a[1] + 10*(a[2] + 10*(a[3] + 10*(a[4] + 10*(a[5] + 10*(a[6] + 10*(a[7] + 10*(a[8] + 10*(a[9])))))))));
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Como seria para entrada com vetor de tamanho 3?

```
; vou tentar obedecer a ordem dos parênteses, portanto, a primeira coisa é carregar a[0] na pilha
aload_0, iconst_0, aiload
; estado atual da pilha: a[0]
; a separação dos elementos da pilha vai ser por #
; agora, põe dez para multiplicar pelo resultado da soma...
ldc#10
; estado atual da pilha: a[0] # 10
; coloca a[1] na pilha
aload_0, iconst_1, aiload
; estado atual da pilha: a[0] # 10 # a[1]
; agora, põe dez para multiplicar pelo resultado da soma...
ldc#10
; estado atual da pilha: a[0] # 10 # a[1] # 10
; põe a[2] na pilha. depois desse passo, basta por os operadores
aload_0, iconst_2, aiload
; estado atual da pilha: a[0] # 10 # a[1] # 10 # a[2]
; primeira operação: multiplicação
imul
; estado atual da pilha: a[0] # 10 # a[1] # 10*a[2]
; soma...
iadd
; estado atual da pilha: a[0] # 10 # a[1] + 10*a[2]
; multiplica...
imul
; estado atual da pilha: a[0] # 10*a[1] + 100*a[2]
; soma
iadd
; estado atual da pilha: a[0] + 10*a[1] + 100*a[2]
; pronto, só falta retornar
ireturn
```

Para um total de 16 bytecodes, que nem no exemplo anterior. A diferença aqui é que diminuímos a quantidade de constantes no código, portanto poderemos ter alguma vantagem da utilização da localidade temporal dos campos de memória.

## Comparando performance do código

Alguns meses atrás respondi uma pergunta em Java sobre [performance de métodos de ordenação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/235636/64969). Para tal, elaborei todo um esquema de teste. Expliquei mais da metodologia lá. Após executar os testes, você obtém média e desvio padrão dos tempos de execução.

Basicamente o problema aqui é adaptar a função de geração de números aleatórios na função `calculaTempo`. Vou postar a original para referência, para então adaptarmos ao mundo de até 10 inteiros distintos, inteiros esses valendo de `[0,10)`, fechado no começo e aberto no final:

```
public static LongSupplier calculaTempo(Consumer<Array> metodoOrdenacao) {
    return () -> {
        Array a = Array.getRandomArray(SIZE_ARRAY);

        long init = System.currentTimeMillis();
        metodoOrdenacao.accept(a);
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - init;
    };
}
```

Para mudar para `calculaSoma`, vou montar o vetor na mão eu mesmo. Para tal, vou usar de um gerador de números aleatórios `r` que vou prover junto com meus argumentos (sim, como `IntSupplier`). A função [`Random.nextInt(n)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) provê valores inteiros no intervalo `[0, n)`. Se eu usar `n=10`, *voi là*, tenho o intervalo exatamente como havia sido especulado. Vou chamar essa variável de `fornece_0_10` para indicar que é um `IntSupplier` que retornará resultados no intervalo fechado no começo e aberto no final `[0,10)`. Como não interessa calcular a soma do vetor no caso trivial em que seu tamanho é 0, mas sim no tamanho variando de `[1,11)`, o tamanho do vetor será `1 + fornece_0_10.getAsInt()`:

```
public static LongSupplier calculaTempo(IntSupplier fornece_0_10, Consumer<int[]> calculaSoma) {
    return () -> {
        int sizeOfA = 1 + fornece_0_10.getAsInt();
        int []a = new int[sizeOfA];

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfA; i++) {
            a[i] = fornece_0_10.getAsInt();
        }

        long init = System.currentTimeMillis();
        calculaSoma.accept(a);
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - init;
    };
}
```

Para chamar essa função, basta iniciar um gerador de números aleatórios `r` e assar a função lambda `() -> r.nextInt(10)` (considerando todas essas funções como estáticas da classe `Soma`):

```
Random r = new Random();
IntSupplier fornece_0_10 = () -> r.nextInt(10);

Estatisticas estatisticaSomaAsc = repeatGetEstatisticas(N_REPETITION, calculaTempo(fornece_0_10, Soma::soma_asc));
Estatisticas.printEstatisticas(estatisticaSomaAsc, "SOMA ASCENDENTE");

Estatisticas estatisticaSomaForeach = repeatGetEstatisticas(N_REPETITION, calculaTempo(fornece_0_10, Soma::soma_foreach));
Estatisticas.printEstatisticas(estatisticaSomaForeach , "SOMA FOREACH");

Estatisticas estatisticaSomaDesc = repeatGetEstatisticas(N_REPETITION, calculaTempo(fornece_0_10, Soma::soma_desc));
Estatisticas.printEstatisticas(estatisticaSomaDesc , "SOMA DESC");

Estatisticas estatisticaSomaDesenrolada1 = repeatGetEstatisticas(N_REPETITION, calculaTempo(fornece_0_10, Soma::soma_desenrolada_1));
Estatisticas.printEstatisticas(estatisticaSomaDesenrolada1 , "SOMA DESENROLADA V1");

Estatisticas estatisticaSomaDesenrolada2 = repeatGetEstatisticas(N_REPETITION, calculaTempo(fornece_0_10, Soma::soma_desenrolada_2));
Estatisticas.printEstatisticas(estatisticaSomaDesenrolada2 , "SOMA DESENROLADA V2");
```

Agora só falta coletar os resultados. Quando maior o número de repetições definido em `N_REPETITION`, mais confiável serão os resultados. Como `Random` fornece números aleatórios em [distribuição uniforme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)), os valores obtidos se equilibram quando o número de repetições tende ao infinito.

> Falta colocar o resultado dos testes para ver qual o mais eficiente