# Quanto cada função "custa" para o servidor

Tags: php, funções, desempenho

Minha dúvida é em relação a função [is_dir](http://www.php.net/is_dir) para averiguar se existe um diretório.

Quanto custa para a aplicação o uso desta função?

Como medir o uso desta ou de outra função no PHP?

A função [file_exists](http://www.php.net/file_exists), por exemplo, segundo dizem custa 12 vezes mais para carregar uma aplicação simples.

Comment: Eu diria para você mensurar esses valores. Mas às vezes isso não é exatamente fácil de medir ou mesmo mensurável. Eu fiz uma pergunta sobre como mensurar s diferença entre dois algoritmos rápidos em Java. Creio que em PHP seja menos caótico porque (se não me engano) não há JIT. Se quiser se aventurar e conhecer algumas limitações desses tipos de teste, boa leitura: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/258476/64969 (PS: os comentários na pergunta são edificantes também, vale a pena lê-los)

Comment: Medir em programação é sempre relativo, só vale para comparar, cite outra função que você queira comparar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não temos como saber.

O tempo depende da capacidade do equipamento e outros fatores de configuração. Isso considerando sempre as mesmas condições.

Depende das condições que está executando naquele momento. As coisas não são tão lineares assim como está pensando.

E depende onde está sendo aplicada. Com dados diferentes o tempo será diferente.

Medir o tempo de uma função é algo um pouco complicado, principalmente em um servidor com carga e em aplicação web. O que medir em uma situação pode não ser reproduzido em outra.

Até onde sei PHP sequer provê ferramentas adequadas para medir bem rodando nestas circunstâncias. É provável que tenha alguma coisa mais avançada, talvez de terceiros que facilite a verificação.

E vai medir para que? Tem que ter um objetivo. Sabendo da informação fará o que com ela?

O parágrafo final diz algo que não parece ter muito sentido, não consigo imaginar o que a chamada dessa função tem a ver com a carga da aplicação e de onde vem esse número 12.

Comment: Apenas para complementar. Se a função fosse uma caixa preta completa, você ainda assim consegue saber se ela tem um tempo mensurável ou não. Se após coletar uma quantia significativa de dados sobre o seu custo em tempo, então você poderia calcular a média e o desvio padrão desses dados. Se o desvio padrão for uma coisa grande, comparável com os valores obtidos/média dos dados, então você não tem como conseguir ter uma margem de resultado boa, portanto a sua medida é incapaz de lhe dizer alguma coisa sobre o que foi medido. Seria como ter uma pesquisa de opinião com margem de 40% no resultado