# Como medir o tempo de execução de uma função com precisão em C++

Tags: c++, desempenho

Estou realizando um trabalho da faculdade e preciso medir o tempo de execução de uma função recursiva, porém quando eu faço a medição em nanosegundos a maior parte dos meus dados volta zerado.

Teria alguma forma de fazer uma medição mais precisa em C++ ? Em anexo está como fiz utilizando a biblioteca `chrono`:

```
auto t1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
resultado = fiboRec(n);
auto t2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
cout << "O numero de Fibonacci na posicao " << n << " eh "<< resultado;
cout << "O tempo gasto foi de " << duration << " nanosegundos" << endl;
```

Alguns dos resultados obtidos foram os seguintes:

```
O numero de Fibonacci na posicao 20 eh 6765 O tempo gasto foi de 0 nanosegundos
O numero de Fibonacci na posicao 20 eh 6765 O tempo gasto foi de 1000000 nanosegundos
O numero de Fibonacci na posicao 22 eh 17711 O tempo gasto foi de 0 nanosegundos
O numero de Fibonacci na posicao 24 eh 46368 O tempo gasto foi de 999800 nanosegundos
O numero de Fibonacci na posicao 26 eh 121393 O tempo gasto foi de 0 nanosegundos
O numero de Fibonacci na posicao 28 eh 317811 O tempo gasto foi de 1998600 nanosegundos
```

Comment: Já chegou a se questionar se realmente o processamento não é rápido o suficiente para não ser detectado no intervalo de tempo perceptível para a versão da biblioteca `chrono` compilada na sua máquina? Por exemplo, qual o valor de `n` para a verificação?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/258476/64969

Comment: não sei se entendi bem, mas ai vai a saida que eu recebo do programa para alguns valores
O numero de Fibonacci na posicao 20 eh 6765 O tempo gasto foi de 0 nanosegundos O numero de Fibonacci na posicao 20 eh 6765 O tempo gasto foi de 1000000 nanosegundos
O numero de Fibonacci na posicao 22 eh 17711 O tempo gasto foi de 0 nanosegundos
O numero de Fibonacci na posicao 24 eh 46368 O tempo gasto foi de 999800 nanosegundos
O numero de Fibonacci na posicao 26 eh 121393 O tempo gasto foi de 0 nanosegundos
O numero de Fibonacci na posicao 28 eh 317811 O tempo gasto foi de 1998600 nanosegundos

Comment: um problema possivel pode ser que meu computador esta salvando a respota e isso esta afetando o tempo em que ele leva para calcular, mas não sei como resolver isso

Comment: Não há como o computador estar guardando os dados do retorno da função. Nesse caso aqui não é cache de uma resposta http. Ele só faria isso de por acaso você tivesse ensinado

Comment: Outra coisa que o seu experimento de performance não está levando em consideração são fatores aleatórios. Num sistema multi-processado, cada núcleo de processamento só pode executar uma thread de cada vez. Isso significa que, caso o núcleo que estivesse processando o seu programa seja desviado para outra atividade (e isso é comum, evita que o outro processo "morra de fome"), o tempo em que o núcleo de processamento passou executando o _outro programa_ vai ser levado em consideração na sua contagem. Sem falar de flutuações aleatórias também não estão sendo descartadas...

Comment: Uma das maneiras mais comuns de se descartar essas flutuações do experimento que você não tem pleno controle é rodá-lo diversas e diversas vezes e obter uma média. Está linkado no meu segundo comentário coisas sobre o assunto. É importante ler a pergunta que eu disse ser relacionada e, também, os links dentro dela para se ter uma ideia melhor de onde você está caminhando ao testar performance

Comment: Para tempos tão pequenos geralmente o *throughput* (número de operações em uma certa quantidade de tempo) é mais importante do que o tempo de cada operação individual. O *throughput* também te dá uma boa noção da média dos temos individuais (basta dividir a quantidade de tempo pela quantidade de operações). Nesse sentido vale a pena usar uma biblioteca como [Google benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark) para calcular o *throughput* e evitar boa parte das armadilhas mencionadas pelo Jefferson Quesado.

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver compilando para windows pode tentar o QueryPerformanceCounter, mas não acredito que consiga uma melhora tão significativa.

Então a melhor opção é executar a função N vezes e tirar uma média.

*obs: os numeros nunca vão ser absolutos, vão ser relativos a presença de outros processos disputando a RAM e o clock da CPU, que ira aumentar/diminuir de acordo com uso.