# Este código está-me a conduzir a um ciclo infinito e não consigo perceber porquê

Tags: c, loop, ciclo-infinito

Este código está-me a conduzir a um ciclo infinito e não consigo perceber porquê.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void
troca (double *n1, double *n2)
{
    double n;

    n    = *n1;
    *n1  = *n2;
    *n2  = n  ;
}

void
ordena (double *r, int size)
{
    int t;
    int i;

    while (1)
    {
        t = 0;
        {
            for (i=0;i<size-1;i++)
            {
                if(r[i] > r[i+1])
                {
                    troca (&r[i], &r[i+1]);
                    t      = 1          ;
                }
            }
        if(t == 0)
            break;
        }
    }
}


int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE   *f1   ;
    int    i     ;
    int    j=0   ;
    int    N     ;               
    int    k     ;             
    double Min   ;
    double Max   ;
    double *reais;           
    double n     ;
    char    c    ;

    sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&N)   ;
    sscanf(argv[2],"%lf",&Min);
    sscanf(argv[3],"%lf",&Max);

    f1    = fopen("f1.txt", "wb")            ; 

    srand(time(NULL));

    while (1)
    {

    if (j == 0)
    {
        reais = (double*)malloc((N)*sizeof(double));
        j=1;
    }

    else
        reais = realloc(reais, (N)*sizeof(double));

    n = Max - Min;
    for (i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        reais[i] = Max - ((double) rand()/(double) RAND_MAX )*n;
        //printf("%9lf",reais[i]);
    }

    ordena(reais, N);

    k = 0;
    for (i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        printf("%9lf",reais[i]);
        k++;

        if (k == 5)
        {
            k = 0;
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    printf("\nDeseja repetir as operacoes:\n1-Repetir\n2-Sair\nR:");
    c = getchar();

    if (c == '1')
    {
        printf("\nIntroduza novos valores de N, Min e Max:");
        scanf("%d %lf %lf", &N, &Min, &Max);
        continue;
    }

    if (c == '2')
    {
        free(reais);
        break;
    }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

O programa recebe três argumentos da linha de comandos, N, o número de reais que o user quer gerar, Max e Min os limites dos valores gerados. Com esses valores é gerado um vetor de doubles com o tamanho necessário que depois é ordenado. Até aqui funciona tudo bem. O problema é que quando peço novos argumentos, entro num loop infinito

Comment: Cara, primeiro me diz o que você pretende fazer.. com esses nomes de variáveis, não da para entender nada. Fora que, tem 2 `while(1)` no código, sendo que um já é o suficiente para te jogar dentro de um loop infinito.

Comment: O programa recebe três argumentos da linha de comandos, N, o número de reais que o user quer gerar, Max e Min os limites dos valores gerados. Com esses valores é gerado um vetor de doubles com o tamanho necessário que depois é ordenado. Até aqui funciona tudo bem. O problema é que quando peço novos argumentos, entro num loop infinito.

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem o código o problema está no método `ordena`; como você tem um `for` que percorre todas as posições do `r`, não precisa do `while(1)`.

O loop era porque o `t == 0` nunca ocorre, já que sempre que entra na iteração `for (i=0;i<size-1;i++)` esse cara roda e o `t = 1;` também.

```
voi ordena (double *r, int size)
{
    int t = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        if (r[i] > r[i+1])
        {
            troca (&r[i], &r[i+1]);
            t = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

OBS: mantive a estrutura das variáveis e tal, mas tenta usar nomes mais intuitivos, fica bem mais fácil de entender o código.

Além disso, tem algumas coisas pra melhorar, por exemplo o `FILE *f1;`. Você só cria essa variável e abre um arquivo, mas não usa pra nada.

Comment: Eu sei que ainda não usei o ficheiro para nada, estava apenas a testar esta parte em particular. Não penso que o problema  seja por causa dessa função porque o loop infinito ocorre após ela atuar.

Comment: @VascoPinhão testou o método `ordena` assim?? Ainda segue em looping? Se sim, adiciona `printf()` em pontos que você acha que pode ser, ajuda a identificar.

Comment: Devo discordar sobre o laço infinito na ordenação. Em tese, com o `swap` e a operação de comparação funcionando como se espera, vai terminar após umas `size^2 - size` operações de comparação

Answer (score 0):

Você está ordenando usando a estratégia da bolha, com direito a uma flag para marcar se houve trocas ou não.

Matematicamente, você precisa fazer no máximo `o( (n^2 - n)/2 )` operações. Ao rodar uma vez o lado interno, há a garantia de que o maior número estará no final do vetor. Então o próximo lance de ordenação não precisaria ir até a última posição, apenas até a penúltima, então os dois maiores elementos estarão em suas posições definitivas. [Nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/235636/64969), chamei essa estratégia de minimizar a quantidade de repetições de "bubblesort mínimo". Você pode por a flag para indicar que, se não houve nenhum `swap`, então o vetor já está ordenado e não se precisa mais trabalhar nele.

Essa operação do jeito que você está fazendo é lenta. Não se espante com isso. A minha sugestão de melhoria na melhor das hipóteses dobra a velocidade, mas também continua sendo lento (mais informações de performance relativa na [outra resposta linkada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/235636/64969)).

Em tese, a sua ordenação um dia terminaria considerando que a operação de troca esteja correta e que a comparação esteja correta. Não consegui enxergar nenhum problema nessas operações. Se você quiser fazer um debug, porém não tem as ferramentas mais tradicionais para isso, você pode inserir um `printf` para indicar quando houver troca e quais são os valores sendo trocados. Obviamente esse seria um código de depuração que deveria ser removido na versão final.

Então, a falha do laço deve estar em outro ponto. O outro laço que há é na função principal. Você está usando o `getchar()`. O que acontece caso essa função retorne um valor que você não espera? Pelo que entendi do código, ele volta o laço debilmente, sem mudar nenhum dos parâmetros.

Ou talvez ele simplesmente não esteja reagindo ao você digitar? Segundo a [referência da função](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/), ela só retorna no momento em que você pressiona `ENTER`. Não ficou claro para mim o que acontece se você por acaso tiver lido algo anteriormente.

Comment: Já consegui resolver, esqueci-me de limpar o buffer após cada utilização do getchar(), é por isso que estavam a dar coisas estranhas