# Erro no algoritmo de ordenação MergeSort em Java

Tags: java, algoritmo

Eu estava fazendo o algoritmo de ordenação MergeSort no Java para fins de estudos e toda vez que executa dá erro. Já revisei a lógica do algoritmo, já substitui o array de inteiros por um `ArrayList`, já tentei mudar a lógica de parada mas nada.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();

    array.add(0);
    array.add(3);
    array.add(9);
    array.add(18);
    array.add(5);
    array.add(4);
    array.add(6);
    array.add(10);

    MergeSortClass.dividir( array, 0, array.size() );

    System.out.println( array.toString() );

}

public static void dividir( ArrayList<Integer> array, int inicio, int fim ){

    if( inicio < fim ){

        int meio = ( inicio + ( fim - 1 ) ) / 2;

        dividir( array, inicio, meio );
        dividir( array, meio + 1, fim );
        intercalar( array, inicio, meio, fim );

    }

} 

 public static void intercalar( ArrayList<Integer> array, int inicio, int meio, int fim ){

    int i = inicio;
    int j = meio + 1;

    ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();

    while( i < j && j < fim ){

        if( array.get(i) < array.get(j) ){

            temp.add( array.get(i) );
            i++;

        } else {

            temp.add( array.get(j) );
            j++;

        }

    }

    //No caso da árvore recursiva estar desbalanceada e um dos lados terminar de comparar, o restante do outro lado será copiado para o array temporário

    while( i < j ){

        temp.add( array.get(i) );
        i++;

    }

    while( j < fim ){

        temp.add( array.get(j) );
        j++;

    }

    for( i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++ ){

        array.set( i + inicio, temp.get(i) );

        //código abaixo só para testar
        System.out.println( array.get(i + inicio) );

    }

    System.out.println("");

}
```

Após eu rodar o código, no prompt de saída junto com a mensagem de erro, eu recebo isso:

[image: tela de erro]

O array foi quase totalmente ordenado.

Quero saber qual é o problema com meu código e qual a possível solução.

Comment: Você está ofendendo o tamanho do array, é isso que o erro está mostrando. Por algum motivo você mandou ordenar numa posição fora do intervalo `[0, array.size())`

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/235616/64969

Comment: O erro não é de compilação, é na execução, tanto que ele imprime alguns resultados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu programa tem alguns problemas:

1. Se você está trabalhando com listas, não faz sentido chamar a lista de `array`, já que não é um array e sim uma lista.
2. É mais fácil trabalhar com `fim` sendo o último elemento da lista (`lista.size() - 1`) e não o tamanho da lista que seria o primeiro item depois do fim dela. Você até tenta trabalhar com ele sendo o primeiro item depois do fim (usando o `( fim - 1 )` no método `dividir`), mas o código fica mais complicado com isso.
3. **O seu maior problema foi usar o `i < j` no método `intercalar`. O que você queria era `i <= meio`.** Com `i < j` você acaba adicionando os elementos da segunda metade de cada intercalação duas vezes na lista de rascunho resultante, e daí na hora de copiar ela de volta para a lista original, você estoura o tamanho dela.
4. O seu método `dividir` deveria se chamar `ordenar`.
5. Prefira usar os tipos que sejam os mais abstratos possíveis, evitando usar tipos específicos demais. Dessa forma, em muitos locais onde você usa `ArrayList` como tipo, poderia usar simplesmente `List`.

Veja ele aqui corrigido:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class MergeSortClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        lista.add(0);
        lista.add(3);
        lista.add(9);
        lista.add(18);
        lista.add(5);
        lista.add(4);
        lista.add(6);
        lista.add(10);
        ordenar(lista);
        System.out.println(lista.toString());
    }

    public static void ordenar(List<Integer> lista) {
        ordenar(lista, 0, lista.size() - 1);
    }

    private static void ordenar(List<Integer> lista, int inicio, int fim) {
        if (inicio >= fim) return;

        int meio = (inicio + fim) / 2;

        ordenar(lista, inicio, meio);
        ordenar(lista, meio + 1, fim);
        intercalar(lista, inicio, meio, fim);
    }

    private static void intercalar(List<Integer> lista, int inicio, int meio, int fim) {

        int i = inicio;
        int j = meio + 1;

        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>(fim - inicio + 1);

        while (i <= meio && j <= fim) {
            int a = lista.get(i);
            int b = lista.get(j);
            if (a < b) {
                temp.add(a);
                i++;
            } else {
                temp.add(b);
                j++;
            }
        }

        while (i <= meio) {
            temp.add(lista.get(i));
            i++;
        }

        while (j <= fim) {
            temp.add(lista.get(j));
            j++;
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < temp.size(); k++) {
            lista.set(k + inicio, temp.get(k));
        }
    }
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/MRlyCz)

Comment: A duas respostas anteriores não resolveram o problema, pq eu sei que o último valor válido é "size() - 1", mas se perceberem todas as condicionais usam "<" ao invés de "<=", isso faz com que seja considerado como verdadeiro todos os valores menos o último (que seria o tamanho total do array)

Comment: Achei interessante suas dicas a respeito nomenclatura. A solução de usar 'i <= meio' e 'j <= fim' realmente funcionou, só não entendo o porquê, já que i <= meio é a mesma coisa que i < j. Deve ser alguma coisa relacionada a explodir o índice da lista, mas obrigado.

Comment: @JuliusZiegler `i <= meio` não é a mesma coisa que `i < j`. Lembre-se que o `j` muda dentro desse `while`, enquanto que o `meio` não muda.

Comment: Tem razão, não tinha percebido isso

Answer (score 1):

O mais importante em situações como essa é saber ler a saída de erro. É algo muito simples, mas que, em geral, as pessoas ignoram.

Primeiro, deve-se notar que a saída de erro é dada em formato de uma pilha. Isso significa que a primeira linha do erro representa o último método que foi chamado e onde, **efetivamente**, a exceção ocorreu.

No seu caso, o erro aconteceu nesse trecho:

```
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
```

`rangeCheck` é um método da classe `ArrayList` que checa se um dado índice (`int`) está dentro dos limites do vetor. Caso não esteja, então uma exceção do tipo  `IndexOutOfBoundsException` é lançada.

Veja [aqui](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.rangeCheck%28int%29) uma implementação da ArrayList para a `OpenJDK`. O trecho de código abaixo é o método `rangeCheck`.

```
/**
 * Checks if the given index is in range.  If not, throws an appropriate
 * runtime exception.  This method does *not* check if the index is
 * negative: It is always used immediately prior to an array access,
 * which throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if index is negative.
 */
private void rangeCheck(int index) {
    if (index >= size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
}
```

Continuando a análise do erro...

Note que o `rangeCheck` é chamado pelo método `java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList:448)`, outro método da `ArrayList`. Esse, por sua vez, é chamado pelo método `intercalar` da sua classe `MergeSortClass`. O `intercalar` é chamado pelo `dividir` e esse pelo `main`.

O erro, dentro do `intercalar`, acontece nessa linha:

```
array.set( i + inicio, temp.get(i) );
```

Portanto, essa chamada ao `set` está gerando a exceção `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Resumindo: o primeiro parametro `i+inicio` está fora do limite do vetor (a estrutura interna do ArrayList).

Comment: `i < temp.size()` já significa que o `i` nunca irá até `temp.size()`. Ao colocar o `- 1`, o último elemento seria então esquecido.

Comment: Tem razão @VictorStafusa! hahahah. Passou totalmente batido! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Experimente `MergeSortClass.dividir( array, 0, array.size()-1 );` porque o size do ArrayList é a quantidade de elementos, mas como começa em 0 a última posição válida é size-1.

Comment: Você viu o `fim - 1` no método `dividir`?