# Como fazer um algoritmo em Java que possa medir o tempo de execução do algoritmo de ordenação Heap Sort?

Tags: java, algoritmo

Iniciei meu algoritmo dessa maneira para que seja capaz de medir seu tempo de execução, mas não tenho certeza se está certo, como dar continuidade com um exemplo:

```
package heapsort;

public class Heapsort {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int quantidade = 1000;
        int[] vetor = new int[quantidade];
        int tamanho;

        for(int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++){
            vetor[i] = (int) (Math.random()*quantidade);
        }

        long tempoInicial = System.currentTimeMillis();


    }

}
```

Comment: Obtém a hora imediatamente antes de executar, obtém a hora imediatamente depois de executar. Subtrai uma da outra. Tá aí o algoritmo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: Eu tenho um projeto criado para medir essas coisas. Criei para fazer esta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/235636/64969

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa primeiro guardar o currentTimeMillis() inicial e depois comparar com o final.

```
long tempoInicial = System.currentTimeMillis();

// execução do método

System.out.println("O método foi executado em " + System.currentTimeMillis() - tempoInicial);
```

System.currentTimeMillis() é um função que retorna a diferença, medida em milissegundos, entre a hora atual e a meia-noite de 1º de janeiro de 1970 UTC (horário universal coordenado).

Comment: Acredito que o System.currentTimeMillis() seja mais preciso